# How to properly debug and inspect SQL Queries in PHP File?

Tags: mysql, logs, performance, slow-log, query-performance

My website *AdminPanel* has a PHP file which takes almost **30-40** seconds in loading.  I doubt the queries which are making the mess, but may be it is the code but the code structure seems perfect. I want to find and check the all the queries execution and running time i.e **how much time it takes to execute?** But i can't.

I tried the **slow query logs** option but it is not logging anything. And from the general log i just see queries but no execution time and details.

Thanks

Comment: More on slow log usage:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis -- a common mistake is not setting `log_output`.

Answer (score 1):

SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 1;
to log slow queries taking 1 second or more.

EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ..... to see valuable information about how the query is getting to the result.

Follow immediately in the same session,
SHOW WARNINGS;
to see how the Optimizer rearranged the sequence of events.
(Rick James, thanks for the reminder.)

Comment: (And `SHOW WARNINGS;` so you can see the  "extended" stuff.)